# ¿Cómo Eliminar o hacer invisible un texto en canvas sin quitar el lienzo?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

Hize un texto en Canvas, y quiero eliminarlo o hacerlo invisible sin tener que eliminar el lienzo completo. ¿Qué puedo hacer? ¿Cómo puedo crear un botón que al tocarlo desactive, quite, o oculte el texto?

Aquí mi código :

```
from tkinter import *
lienzo = Canvas(width=400, height=300, bg='white')
lienzo.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
lienzo.create_text(200, 40, font=("Purusa", 30), text='Texto ejemplo', fill='black')
mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para borrar un lienzo, se utiliza el método delete. Darle el parámetro especial "all" para eliminar todos los elementos del lienzo (la cadena "all" "es una etiqueta especial que representa a todos los elementos del lienzo):

`canvas.delete("all")`

Si desea eliminar sólo ciertos elementos en el lienzo (tales como objetos en primer plano, mientras que deja los objetos de fondo de la pantalla) puede asignar etiquetas a cada elemento. Entonces, en lugar de "all", se podría suministrar el nombre de una etiqueta